# Unpack a Mono in a recursive call?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am working on a service which is supposed to call a downstream service, and based on the response of that downstream service, my next recursion will be called.

Here is the example code for reference

```kotlin
private fun rec(storeId: Int, listOfMonos: ArrayList<Mono<*>>, visited: HashSet<CartesianCoordinate>, previousCartesianCoordinate: CartesianCoordinate?, destinations: List<PathingCartesianPosition>) {
    if(visited.size == destinations.size)
        return
    val currentCoordinate = findClosestCoordinate(destinations, previousCartesianCoordinate, visited)
    var startingCoordinate = previousCartesianCoordinate
    currentCoordinate.first?.let { visited.add(it) }
    val queryString = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(currentCoordinate.first?.let {
        previousCartesianCoordinate?.let { it1 ->
            PathServiceQuery(
                it1,
                it
            )
        }
    })
    listOfMonos.add(webClient.getPath(storeId, queryString, currentCoordinate.second))

    listOfMonos.last {
        println("YY")
        it.flatMap { x ->
            println("ZZ")
            if(!(x as PathingCartesianResponse).coordinates.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                println("XX")
                currentCoordinate.first?.let { it1 -> startingCoordinate = it1 }
            }
            Mono.just(x)
        }
        true
    }
    rec(storeId, listOfMonos, visited, startingCoordinate, destinations)
}
```

The downstream service is called via `webClient` which returns a `Mono`.
I just need to check if it returns an empty response or not.
Can this be achieved only via blocking?

As you can see here, only `YY` is printed, and not `XX` or `ZZ`. Can it be done without blocking?